# The request content-type is not a multipart/form-data in Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

HTML form

```
<html>
        <!--// This the client html page that receive data and uploads it.>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>JSP Page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <body>
        <center>
                <h1>Task It User profile page</h1><br></br>

            <form  action="Upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <table border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>First Name: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="firstName" size="50"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Last Name: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="lastName" size="50"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Portrait Photo: </td>
                        <td><input type="file" name="photo" size="50"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <input type="submit" value="Save">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </center>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Servlet

```
   package net.codejava.upload;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.SQLException;

    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import javax.servlet.http.Part;

    @WebServlet("/Upload")
    @MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 16177215)    // upload file's size up to 16MB
    public class FileUpload extends HttpServlet {

        // database connection settings
        private String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/appdb";
        private String dbUser = "root";
        private String dbPass = "asdf";

        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            doPost(request, response);
        }

        @Override
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            // gets values of text fields
            String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
            String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");

            InputStream inputStream = null; // input stream of the upload file

            // obtains the upload file part in this multipart request
            Part filePart = request.getPart("photo");
            if (filePart != null) {
                // prints out some information for debugging
                System.out.println(filePart.getName());
                System.out.println(filePart.getSize());
                System.out.println(filePart.getContentType());

                // obtains input stream of the upload file
                inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();
            }

            Connection conn = null; // connection to the database
            String message = null;  // message will be sent back to client

            try {
                // connects to the database
                DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUser, dbPass);

                // constructs SQL statement
                String sql = "INSERT INTO contacts (first_name, last_name, photo) values (?, ?, ?)";
                PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                statement.setString(1, firstName);
                statement.setString(2, lastName);

                if (inputStream != null) {
                    // fetches input stream of the upload file for the blob column
                    statement.setBlob(3, inputStream);
                }

                // sends the statement to the database server
                int row = statement.executeUpdate();
                if (row > 0) {
                    message = "File uploaded and saved into database";
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                message = "ERROR: " + ex.getMessage();
              //  ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (conn != null) {
                    // closes the database connection
                    try {
                        conn.close();
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                // sets the message in request scope
                request.setAttribute("Message", message);

                // forwards to the message page
                getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/message.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }
        }
    }
```

- The second code is the servlet code that i am trying to use to store data from client into the appdb

  - javax.servlet.ServletException: The request content-type is not a multipart/form-data is the error that i am getting.
- I am very new this so if there is a trivial mistake, still answer the question

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean

Comment: When asking a question about an exception thrown by some code, always post the complete stack trace of the exception, and the relevant code.

Comment: Refer [BalusC's answer - How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet#2424824) might be useful for you.